# My own implementation of Linq SelectMany extension method

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, linq, extension-methods

What do you think of my own implementation of the extension method `SelectMany`?
Motivating criticism is always welcome.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelectMany<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
{
    var theList = new List<TResult>();

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        foreach (TResult inneritem in selector(item))
        {
            theList.Add(inneritem);
        }
    }

    return theList as IEnumerable<TResult>;
}
```

Comment: You're doing this just as a learning exercise, right? Otherwise, reimplementing framework code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Just to learn indeed. Fooling around with extension methods and delegates etc... :)

Comment: For a detailed explanation about how to implement all of LINQ extension methods, see [Jon Skeet's series Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx). Specifically, [part 9 is about `SelectMany()`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `as` cast in the return statement is entirely redundant, it doesn’t serve a purpose.

Furthermore, The problem with this implementation is that it’s not lazy. You should use a `yield` generator instead.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelectMany<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
        foreach (TResult inneritem in selector(item))
            yield return inneritem;
}
```

If C# already had a `yield from` statement, this would be even shorter since you wouldn’t need to iterate the inner items explicitly.